# How to remove the parentheses around records when saveAsTextFile on RDD[(String, Int)]?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-pig

How do I remove the parenthesis "(" and ")" from the output by the below spark job?

When I try to read the spark output using PigScript it creates a problem.

**My code:**

```
scala> val words = Array("HI","HOW","ARE")
words: Array[String] = Array(HI, HOW, ARE)

scala> val wordsRDD = sc.parallelize(words)
wordsRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at    parallelize at <console>:23

scala> val keyvalueRDD = wordsRDD.map(elem => (elem,1))
keyvalueRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at <console>:25

scala> val wordcountRDD = keyvalueRDD.reduceByKey((x,y) => x+y)
wordcountRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ShuffledRDD[2] at reduceByKey at <console>:27

scala> wordcountRDD.saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/outputfiles")
```

**Output as per above code :**

```
 hadoop dfs -cat /user/cloudera/outputfiles/part*

(HOW,1)
(ARE,1)
(HI,1)
```

But I want the output of spark to be stored as below as without parenthesis

```
HOW,1
ARE,1
HI,1
```

Now I want to read the above output using a PigScript.

LOAD statement in Pigscript treats "(HOW" as first atom and "1)" as second atom

Is there anyway we can get rid off parenthesis in spark code itself as  I don't want to apply the fix  for this in pigscript..

**Pig script :**

```
records = LOAD '/user/cloudera/outputfiles' USING PigStorage(',') AS (word:chararray);
dump records;
```

**Pig output :**

```
 ((HOW)
 ((ARE)
 ((HI)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map` transformation before you save the records to `outputfiles` directory, e.g.

```
wordcountRDD.map { case (k, v) => s"$k, $v" }.saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/outputfiles")
```

See [Spark's documentation about map](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@map[U](f:T=%3EU)(implicitevidence$3:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[U]).

---

I strongly recommend using Datasets instead.

```
scala> words.toSeq.toDS.groupBy("value").count().show
+-----+-----+
|value|count|
+-----+-----+
|  HOW|    1|
|  ARE|    1|
|   HI|    1|
+-----+-----+

scala> words.toSeq.toDS.groupBy("value").count.write.csv("outputfiles")

$ cat outputfiles/part-00199-aa752576-2f65-481b-b4dd-813262abb6c2-c000.csv
HI,1
```

See [Spark SQL, DataFrames and Datasets Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html).

Answer (score 1):

This format is a format of Tuple. You can manually define your format:

```
val wordcountRDD = keyvalueRDD.reduceByKey((x,y) => x+y)
                              // here we set custom format
                              .map(x => x._1 + "," + x._2)
wordcountRDD.saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/outputfiles")
```